# how to center horizonally everything in forms

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

so in my render function, I have

```
 render() {
     <div>
        <form id="one">
          <TextField id="t1" ... />
          <Button id="b1" />
        </form>

        <div id="empty"><div/>

        <form id="two">
          <TextField id="t2" ... />
          <TextField id="t3" ... />
          <Button id="b2" />
        </form>

     </div>
  }
```

and i'm trying to center everything horizontally. the 'empty' div in between the forms are to create space between the forms.

How can I do this?

Thanks !

Comment: `material-ui` has a [Grid system](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/), you might wanna check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Grid system from react bootstrap, With help of Row and Col you will have better control over displaying your controls horizontally and vertically. This is the link for more info. https://react-bootstrap.netlify.com/layout/grid/#grid